# Rewrite .htaccess for https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an .htaccess file on my http site. Our system administrator made https settings and I can get my site by https. But the problem is that I can't rewrite .htaccess file.
For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings|admin|adminNewDesign)\/([A-Za-z]*)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This works fine on http, but doesn't work on https.
I tried like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} On
RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings|admin|adminNewDesign)\/([A-Za-z]*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

And it doesn't work also. How to do it properly?

Comment: Question not about programming? There are a lot of htaccess questions here. I removed php tag, sory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently redirecting only when the `HTTPS` flag is **`ON`**, which is obviously, not what you want.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings|admin|adminNewDesign)/([a-z]*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thax, I'll check your answer tomorrow.

Comment: I've checked it. Thanx, I have forced https now. But last rewrite rule doesn't works at all. When I go to /getReadings/icom I receive page not found error.

Comment: Omg. Dude. There was spasce after ^ on first rewrite rule. It worked fine with forced https but other rewrite rules were not working. I removed space and it's fine now.