# Ask htaccess to redirect from https.*

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have an htaccess that forses user to use https and implements some semantic url.
Here it is:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteRule ^https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings|admin|adminNewDesign)\/([A-Za-z]*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^adminNewDesign$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/adminNewDesign/addingOperators/i [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^admin$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/admin.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(index)/(reg)/(byphone|byemail)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php?id=$2&loginform=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings|admin|adminNewDesign)/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php?id=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings)/(fullpage)/(true)/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/php?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(admin|adminNewDesign)\/([A-Za-z]*)/([A-Za-z]*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php?id=$2&device=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^adminNewDesign\/(individualAnalogueNotification|analogueNotification|intercomNotification)/record-([0-9]+)\.wav$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/play_audio.php?recordType=$1&record_id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

It works fine, for example redirects from index/test to https://hostname.ru/index.php?id=test.
But when I go to adminNewDesign it redirects to https://hostname.ru/adminNewDesign/addingOperators/i

When I used http another rule worked here, this one:

```
RewriteRule ^(admin|adminNewDesign)\/([A-Za-z]*)/([A-Za-z]*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php?id=$2&device=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But last redirect doesn't work now, it gives 404 mistake.
So looks like `^(admin|adminNewDesign)\/([A-Za-z]*)/([A-Za-z]*)$` suits http://hostname.ru/admin but doesn't suits https://hostname.ru/admin .
So, how can I show htaccess to redirect from https like urls?

Answer (score 0):

You need just one redirect at top for `https=>http` and rest should be internal rewrites like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings|admin|adminNewDesign)/([A-Za-z]*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^adminNewDesign/?$ adminNewDesign/addingOperators/i [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin.php [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(index)/(reg)/(byphone|byemail)?/?$ $1.php?id=$2&loginform=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings|admin|adminNewDesign)/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings)/(fullpage)/(true)/?$ $1/php?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(admin|adminNewDesign)/([A-Za-z]*)/([A-Za-z]*)/÷$ $1.php?id=$2&device=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^adminNewDesign\/(individualAnalogueNotification|analogueNotification|intercomNotification)/record-([0-9]+)\.wav$ play_audio.php?recordType=$1&record_id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Strange, but this doesn't work at all.
https://domainname.ru/getReadings/icom shows me 404. I cleared cache of my chrome and open it in incognito mode.

Comment: Also, man from my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747480/rewrite-htaccess-for-https 
suggested adding https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ to redirection. It worked better.

Comment: Where is `getReadings.php` located? And what is `DocumentRoot` of `https` site?